# Text file 2D array guidance needed

Tags: visual-c++, switch-statement, text-files, multidimensional-array

This program need to read a text file :

Amy 100 100 90 95 85 100 90 100 100 98 75

Bob 90 92 82 95 89 93 95 97 96 98 92

Nina 100 90 95 85 100 65 75 95 100 90 60

Eva 98 90 95 85 100 90 90 95 100 90 82

Matt 100 100 90 95 85 75 85 90 95 100 78

Shiva 90 90 95 100 75 100 100 90 92 82 68

and later prompt the user to choose a name using a switch statement and present the highest lowest and average grade for the choice entered.

This is what i have been working on.

how do i allow my switch statement to obtain the info from the array? Also "i get error for the format (file>>name[])

```
using namespace std;

void PrintLines (int numlines); //for the border "*"
int main()
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    ifstream file;
    ofstream file;
    file.open("gradename.txt"); 
    if(file.fail())
    {
        cout<< ("cant open text");
        //system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    string name[6]; //array to store the names
    int scores[6][11]; //array to store the scores
    int x, y;
    for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        file>>name[x]; //change this error?
        for(int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
            file >> scores[x][y];
    }

    {
        int number = 0; 
        double ave = 0.0 ;
        double sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 100;
        int selection=0;

        while (!file.eof())
        {
            if(count != 0) 
            {
                if(number>max)
                    max=number;
                    if(number<min)
                        min=number;
            }
            sum+=number;
            count+=1;
            file>>number;
        }

        ave = sum / (count-1);

        ////end of calculation
        int numlines=0; //initializing new variable to print *
        cout<< "\nHow many lines of * do you want to print"<<endl; //asking user for input for 
        border *
        cin>> numlines;
        PrintLines(numlines);

        cout<<"\n\n Whose grades would you like to see\n 
        Enter 1 for Amy, 2 for Bob or 3 for Nina, 

        4 for Eva, 5 for Matt or 6 for Shiva.... \n "<< endl; // User's choice

        switch(selection) 
        {

            case 1:
                cout << "Amy's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:"<< min << "\nAverage grade:"<< ave << "\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Bob's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:" << min << "\nAverage grade:" << ave << "\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Nina's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:" << min << "\nAverage grade:" << ave << "\n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Eva's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:" << min << "\nAverage grade:" << ave << "\n";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Matt's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:" << min << "\nAverage grade:" << ave << "\n";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Shiva's\n Highest grade is:" << max << "\nLowest grade:" << min << "\nAverage grade:" << ave << "\n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "\n Invalid\n"; 
                break;
        }
        cout << "How many lines of * do you want to print" << endl;
        cin >> numlines;
        PrintLines(numlines);
    }

    file.close(); //closing file
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void PrintLines(int numlines) //function that contains the output for *
{
    for (int count =1; count <=numlines; count++)
    cout << "************************************************************************" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Note: I assumed that your file looks like this:

```
Amy 100 100 90 95 85 100 90 100 100 98 75
Bob 90 92 82 95 89 93 95 97 96 98 92
Nina 100 90 95 85 100 65 75 95 100 90 60
Eva 98 90 95 85 100 90 90 95 100 90 82
Matt 100 100 90 95 85 75 85 90 95 100 78
Shiva 90 90 95 100 75 100 100 90 92 82 68
```

Now the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

void PrintLines (int numlines); //for the border "*"

int main( )

{

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    ifstream file;

    //ofstream file;

    file.open("Path to your file\\gradename.txt");

    if(file.fail()) {
        cout<< ("cant open text");
        return 1;
    }

    map<string, vector<int> > scores; //[6][11]; //array to store the scores

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; ++x) {

        string name;
        file >> name; //change this error?

        vector<int> scoresOfName;
        for(int y = 0; y < 11; y++) {
            int score;
            file >> score;
            scoresOfName.push_back(score);
        }
        scores[name] = scoresOfName;
    }

    {


        int numlines;
        cout<< "\nHow many lines of * do you want to print"<

        cin >> numlines;

        PrintLines(numlines);

        cout<<"\n\n Whose grades would you like to see\n Enter 1 for Amy, 2 for Bob or 3 for Nina,4 for Eva, 5 for Matt or 6 for Shiva.... \n "<< endl; // User's choice
        int selection;
        cin >> selection;
        string chName = "";
        switch(selection)
        {
        case 1:
            chName = "Amy";
            break;
        case 2:
            chName = "Bob";
            break;
        case 3:
            chName = "Nina";
            break;
        case 4:
            chName = "Eva";
            break;
        case 5:
            chName = "Matt";
            break;
        case 6:
            chName = "Shiva";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\n Invalid input\n";
            break;
        }

        cout << "Your choice is " << chName;


        cout << "\n" << chName << "'s\n Highest grade is:"
             << *(max_element(scores[chName].begin(), scores[chName].end()))
             << "\nLowest grade:"
             << *(min_element(scores[chName].begin(), scores[chName].end()))
             << "\nAverage grade:"
             << accumulate(scores[chName].begin(), scores[chName].end(), 0) / 10
             << "\n";



        cout << "How many lines of * do you want to print" << endl;
        cin >> numlines;
        PrintLines(numlines);

    }

    file.close(); //closing file

    cin.get();

    return 0;

}

void PrintLines(int numlines) //function that contains the output for *

{
    for (int count =1; count <=numlines; count++)
        cout << "********************************************************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! when i tried to build it, i was getting errors...but i realized that it was because i didnt include #include<string>